# User.where() how to call a value from a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Setting with a boolean value "profile_complete: true" How do I call this in my user controller for restricting which users I want to display.
If I was calling all users with a specific role I would say

```
@user = User.where(role: 'admin')
```

But role is defined in the user model. How do I call profile_complete from Setting model?

```
@user = User.where(role: 'admin', profile_complete: 'true')
```

Comment: The relationship is User has_one Setting and Setting belongs_to User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define association between User and Setting model

```
class User
  has_one :setting
end

class Setting
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Use joins using above associations, then you can call profile_complete from Setting model as

```
 @user = User.joins(:setting).where("role = 'admin' AND settings.profile_complete = TRUE")
```